# Text Animation Android Z index

Tags: android, xml, animation

I am making a logo quiz sort of app, for which on a correct answer I want the text/image to come from the Z axis  to the screen, more like a 3d effect inwards. Then the text/image  should move a little too, just like wiggle at its place.
How do I go about?

Thanks in advance! :)

```
if(checkanswer.equalsIgnoreCase(jawab[0])||checkanswer.equalsIgnoreCase(jawab[1])||checkanswer.equalsIgnoreCase(jawab[2]))
            {
                answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                check_answer.setText("CORRECT ANSWER !"); //Correct Answer should wiggle!
                answer.setEnabled(false);

                // Disable SUBMIT button
                submit.setClickable(false);

                // EDIT THE SCORES
                forScores=getSharedPreferences(FileName,0);
                editkar=forScores.edit();
                int score=forScores.getInt("Level "+receiver[1], 0);
                score++;
                editkar.putInt("Level "+receiver[1],score);
                editkar.commit(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the ObjectAnimator class introduced in 3.1 though there's NineOldAndroids library for usage on pre-3.1 platforms.

So first thing I do here is scale the view's X and Y axis and alpha from 0 to 1 in a set so they play together. Then when the animation ends, the wiggle animation starts. It basically moves left and right by 50 pixels. The rest is self explanatory.

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView, "alpha", 0, 1),
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView, "scaleX", 0,  1),
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView, "scaleY", 0, 1)
    );
    set.setDuration(1000).start();

    set.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView, "translationX", 0, 50, -50, 50, -50, 50, -50, 0).setDuration(1000).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Umm thanks, 
I want the text "Correct answer" only to wiggle after the user gets the logo right

I am posting the code.

Comment: Then just do 
`ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(check_answer, "translationX", 0, 50, -50, 50, -50, 50, -50, 0).setDuration(1000).start();` after setting the text to the TextView and remove the animation listener completely.

Answer (score 0):

try Camera: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html, see for some tutorials how to use it

Comment: i can't see any animation here

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to add the animation.
Please help.

Comment: see this for example: http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html?m=1